# Maximum switching frequency

Tags: frequency, frequency-measurement, igbt

Is it possible to calculate maximum switching frequency of IGBT having only datasheet in hands?

https://www.semikron.com/dl/service-support/downloads/download/semikron-datasheet-skm200gal173d-22890495.pdf

Comment: Maybe. Depends on the datasheet which I see you didn't include

Comment: updated question @MCG

Comment: Thanks. This isn't really my expertise so I'd prefer not to answer, but the inclusion of the datasheet should allow for people who *do* know about these devices to answer

Comment: Having it in your hands doesn't mean you have read it.

Comment: What's wrong with fig. 8 - typical switching times?

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr I am newbie in EE, if it is not difficult explain me briefly, please.

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr found how it is done )

Answer (score 1):

You presumably want to know the maximum switching frequency for switching a specific level of current with a specific cooling arrangement. Knowing the maximum switching frequency for switching minimal current can be determined using the switching times would not be of much use.

To properly apply the device, you need to determine the power loss due to switching and the power loss due to carrying current. You then need to determine how to cool the device sufficiently to maintain the junction temperatures within safe limits. To do that, you need to know the behavior of the load current, current vs time for each junction including the diode junctions.

For any practical purpose, the answer is no. You can not determine the maximum switching frequency using just the data sheet. You must analyze the behavior of the load and the cooling system.

Comment: Thank you for answer, Charles. If maximum switching frequency is around 33kHz, how much of it I can use with sufficent cooling and relative good load terms?

Comment: You can use a relatively good percentage of that.